# Multiply a value of a list with the previous value

Tags: python, list

Here's the code that i'm using:

```
pie = []
start = 102
stop = 1
step  = 1

for i in range(stop,start):
  result = (i - step) / 100
  pie.append(result)
print(pie)

for i in pie:
  result = pie[i] * pie[i-1]
  pie.append(result)
print(pie)
```

and here's the error that i'm getting:

```
 TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float
```

Comment: chnage this to `result = (i - step) / 100` this `result = (i - step) // 100`

Comment: NameError on `pie`

Comment: you didn't defined the list `pie` but you are appending elements

Comment: and you might get into a endless loop because you modify the iterable you are iterating over - making it ever longer while iterating it so you'll never reach its end  ....

Comment: I want the floats to stay

Comment: You may also want to look at [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate)

Comment: if you want to multiply with previous value `result = pie[1] * pie[i-1]` why are you not changing `pie[1]` here?

Comment: Hey sorry, that was a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added float numbers in `pie` list:

```
result = (i - step) / 100
    pie.append(result)  # [0.0, 0.01, 0.02, ...]
```

Then you used those numbers here as index:

```
for i in pie:
    result = pie[1] * pie[i - 1]
    pie.append(result)
```

Error is also saying same thing: `list indices must be integers or slices, not float`